# regex to detect trailing comma and/or space separated numbers

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to detect and match some values like that:

```
Lorem ipsum 1,2,3
Lorem ipsum 1,2,3,
Lorem ipsum 1, 2, 3
Lorem ipsum 1 2 3
Lorem 12 ipsum 1 2 3

Lorem ipsum 12,13,14

Lorem ipsum 1,12,15
Lorem ipsum 1/12/15

...and so on...
```

but values like following, are not allowed:

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum 1
Lorem ipsum 2
Lorem ipsum 12
Lorem 12 ipsum 12
Lorem ipsum 1,2,3 and more
```

One more requirement I have, that i need to use it with PHP `preg_match` and extract all mathces into variable

Comment: Hi Leon, could you be a little more precise about what it is you'd like? What is the difference between `Lorem ipsum 1,2,3` on the top box and `Lorem ipsum 1,2,3 and more` on the bottom box?

Comment: the numbers are not in the end of the line

Comment: I am a ***strong*** disbeliever in Stack Overflow's `Downvote`, it is bad policy and used for **censorship**, so I am morally opposed.  Today, however, I was close.  When you say, the numbers are not at the end of the line, what about this one?  This example provided: `Lorem ipsum 1`  There are numbers at the end of the line!  I guess I am just saying that I cannot tell what the request here really is...  BTW, Are you really in Moscow, Russia like your profile says?

Comment: your question is not clear, could you add some details what you do? and provide minimal code

Comment: I mean, that only regex have to only match strings that have 2 or more numbers, separated by some delimiter (space, comma, or slash) at the end of the line.

And yes, I am from Moscow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can get tough, but, if i've understood your use case correctly, this should work:

`(?=\d+[ ,\/])([\d,\/\s]{2,})$`

As shown [in this example](https://regex101.com/r/euvRqi/1)

Breakdown:

- `(?=\d+[ ,\/])` positive lookahead asserting that what comes after must include at least one number and one of a space, comma, or slash
- `([\d,\/\s]{2,})` capture group asserting a match of at least 2 of number space, comma, or slash
- `$` asserts the end of the string

#### NOTE:

if you want to allow multiple spaces, tabs, new lines etc, change `(?=\d+[ ,\/])` to `(?=\d+[\s,\/])`

---

As for getting and working with the matches, something like this should work [as shown in this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0427d12916b6c1488743955a69f8f8084744c038):

```
<?php
$re = '/(?=\d+[ ,\/])([\d,\/\s]{2,})$/';
$str = 'Lorem ipsum 1,2,3
Lorem ipsum 1,2,3,
Lorem ipsum 1, 2, 3
Lorem ipsum 1 2 3
Lorem 12 ipsum 1 2 3

Lorem ipsum 12,13,14

Lorem ipsum 1,12,15
Lorem ipsum 1/12/15

Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum 1
Lorem ipsum 2
Lorem ipsum 12
Lorem 12 ipsum 12
Lorem ipsum 1,2,3 and more';

// just getting an arry so we can loop over them easily
$values = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $str)));

foreach($values as $value) {
    
    echo "'$value'";
    
    preg_match($re, trim($value), $matches);
    
    if (isset($matches[0])) {
        echo " matches...\n";
        $output = preg_split( "/[ ,\/]/", $matches[0]);
        $output = array_map('trim', $output);
        $output = array_filter($output);
        var_dump($output);
    } else {
        echo " doesn't match...";
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Which produces this output:

'Lorem ipsum 1,2,3' matches...

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}


'Lorem ipsum 1,2,3,' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}


'Lorem ipsum 1, 2, 3' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "3"
}


'Lorem ipsum 1 2 3' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}


'Lorem 12 ipsum 1 2 3' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "3"
}


'Lorem ipsum 12,13,14' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "13"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "14"
}


'Lorem ipsum 1,12,15' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "15"
}


'Lorem ipsum 1/12/15' matches...
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "12"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "15"
}


'Lorem ipsum' doesn't match...

'Lorem ipsum 1' doesn't match...

'Lorem ipsum 2' doesn't match...

'Lorem ipsum 12' doesn't match...

'Lorem 12 ipsum 12' doesn't match...

'Lorem ipsum 1,2,3 and more' doesn't match...
```